# Saving more than one entity with one Success callback Mongoose in MongoDB, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a Mongoose model Product where

```
var newProduct : {
   name : "Product 1",
   color : "red",
   categoryId : 1023,
   isAvailbale : true
}

var mongooseProductModel = new products(newProduct);
```

With Mongoose with everything setup I can save Product by calling

```
mongooseProductModel.save(function(err)){
}
```

This works fine when I want to create one product only. But what if I want to create multiple products at one shot? Like in entity framework we can submit a collection of entities to the DBContext and calling save will save all entities with a single save product call. Is it possible to achieve that with Mongoose?

Comment: Not a duplicate I think. The solution accepted in the other thread does not fit my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can call asynchronous save function.
This is example of code, that prepopulates the database with data from JSON object 
https://github.com/vodolaz095/hunt/blob/master/examples/lib/populateDatabase.js

```
var preys = [
  {
    'name': 'Alan Schaefer',
    'scored': false,
    'priority': 10
  },
  {
    'name': 'George Dillon',
    'scored': true,
    'priority': 9
  },
  {
    'name': 'Rick Hawkins',
    'scored': true,
    'priority': 8
  },
  {
    'name': 'Blain Cooper',
    'scored': true,
    'priority': 7
  },
  {
    'name': 'Billy Sole',
    'scored': true,
    'priority': 6
  },
  {
    'name': 'Anna Goncalves',
    'scored': false,
    'priority': 0
  },
];

module.exports = exports = function (hunt) {
  //populating the trophies' collection in database
  hunt.model.Trophy.remove({}, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      hunt.async.map(preys, function (prey, cb) {
        hunt.model.Trophy.create(prey, cb);
      }, function (error, preysSaved) {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        } else {
          console.log('' + preysSaved.length + ' trophies recorded.');
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

this code works via the https://github.com/caolan/async#map function.

so, you can call the function via map on array of JSON objects, and the iterator function will create the mongoose entity from each of thems